# in_app_purchase: not getting product details for iOS

Tags: ios, flutter, in-app-purchase, flutter-in-app-purchase

I'm using the in_app_purchase package to sell consumables and subscriptions.
It's working fine for android but on iOS I cannot get any product details.

```
await InAppPurchase.instance.isAvailable()  //returns true

Set<String> ids = Set.from({'subs_item_purchase', 'pro_account'});
ProductDetailsResponse response = await InAppPurchase.instance.queryProductDetails(ids);


print(response.productDetails); //returns []
print(response.notFoundIDs); //returns [subs_item_purchase, pro_account]
print(response.error); //returns null
```

in App Store connect I created the subscription with the id 'pro_account'. it is in status 'Waiting for Review'.
I also created a sandbox user and logged in.
What do I miss?

Answer (score 3):

The problem was that the apple contract for paid apps did expire. I signed a new one and problem solved